# Drools: Time restricted rule

Tags: java, drools

Drools [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.5.0.Final/drools-expert-docs/html/ch04.html#d0e5150) mentions that rules can use attributes like `date-effective` and `date-expires` to specify an absolute rule validity period.

For example

```
rule "Date-restricted rule"
    date-effective "20.2.2013 8:00"      # 8 AM
    date-expires   "20.2.2013 16:00"     # 4 PM
    when
    then
end
```

Drools also supports periodically repeated rules with interval as `timer(int:)` and cron as `timer(cron:)` but it means that the rule is fired in such points.

## Question:

I am interested if there is any option how to specify periodically available (not fired) rules with time restriction. For example let's image the business hours in some company - the operation can be performed only during official working period but not after hours.

I would like something like this, but it is not Drools valid rule

```
rule "Time-restricted rule"
    time-effective "8:00"      # 8 AM
    time-expires   "16:00"     # 4 PM
    when
    then
end
```

Would be possible to extend such rule to be active only Monday to Friday 8 AM to 4 PM?

---

## Solution (by Esteban Aliverti):

Drools doesn't have a direct support for time-based keywords, but they provide much more powerful calendar mechanism using [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) library. `StatefulSession` or `WorkingMemory` created by `StatelessSession` has methods to define these calendars which can restrict date and time when the rule can be fired.

**Example:**
Rule definition

```
rule "Business hours only"
    calendars "business-hours"
    when
        SomeAttachedClass()
    then
        System.out.println("Rule is fired");
end
```

Calendar definition

```
import org.quartz.impl.calendar.DailyCalendar;

// stateless session and working memory or directly stateful session
StatefulKnowledgeSession memory = session.newWorkingMemory(); 
// interested time range is 8-16, also there is many Calendar implementation, not just Daily
DailyCalendar businessHours = new DailyCalendar( 8, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0 );
// by default, defined time is EXCLUDED, the inversion makes it INCLUDED and excludes the rest
businessHours.setInvertTimeRange( true );
//convert the calendar into a org.drools.time.Calendar
org.drools.time.Calendar businessHoursCalendar = QuartzHelper.quartzCalendarAdapter( businessHours );
//Register the calendar in the session with a name. You must use this name in your rules.
memory.getCalendars().set( "business-hours", businessHoursCalendar );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A better approach is to use `calendar` instead of `timer(cron:)`. I managed to do something similar to what you are looking for following these steps:

When you create the session you have to create and configure a Quartz calendar:

```
//in this case I'm using a DailyCalendar but you can use whatever implementation of Calendar you want
org.quartz.impl.calendar.DailyCalendar businessHours = new org.quartz.impl.calendar.DailyCalendar("business-hours", 8, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0);
businessHours.setInvertTimeRange(true);

//convert the calendar into a org.drools.time.Calendar
org.drools.time.Calendar businessHoursCalendar = QuartzHelper.quartzCalendarAdapter(businessHours);

//Register the calendar in the session with a name. You must use this name in your rules.
ksession.getCalendars().set( "business-hours", businessHoursCalendar );
```

Then in your rule you have to write something like this:

```
rule "Rule X"
    calendars "business-hours"
when
    ...
then
    ...
end
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: Amazing, this is exactly what I need. Thanks a lot for your effort!

Comment: The `QuartzHelper` class is not available in the newer versions of Drools; if you still want to use it, you can download it manually from [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.drools/drools-api/5.1.1/org/drools/runtime/help/QuartzHelper.java/). Also, `org.drools.time.Calendar` has changed to `org.kie.api.time.Calendar` in newer versions of Drools.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution. Maybe a bit of a hack, but it works:

You can create a simple Java class encapsulating the current time and add an instance of this class to the working memory. This class, call it `TimeFact`, has methods like `update(long time): void`, `getDay(): String` and `getTime(): String`. This fact can then be used in the `when` part of a rule, like this:

```
rule "Foo"
when
    TimeFact(day in ("Monday", "Thursday"), time > "16:00:00" && < "17:00:00")
    [more conditions]
then
    [do stuff]
end
```

You will need to update the `TimeFact` (and notify the rule engine of this update) before firing your rules. Still, it has the advantage that rule activation times can be described in the rules themselves, without having to define a possibly large number of `calendars`, thus making this approach much more flexible.

Of course, if you have only a few such timed conditions, like "office hours", then the solution using `calendars` is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, you could use cron expressions as timers. So, you could probably use something like this:

```
timer(cron: * 8-16 * * 1-5 *)
```

**Disclaimer: I didn't test this!**

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thanks for your answer but according to the documentation and `Example 4.29` I guess that this FIRES the rule and that is not what I want. I want to the rule be active, not necessarily fired, during that time

Comment: Did you try it? I mean, rules only fire when all their conditions are met, the only thing you can prevent using timers is their execution. You can't force a rule to be executed.

Comment: This is how I think it works: if the rules conditions are met AND you are in a valid time (according to the cron expression) AND you call fireAllRules(), your rule will be executed. If any of these conditions is not true, the rule is not going to be executed. It would be good if you could try it so we can be sure about the behavior.

Comment: Good thinking. I'll try. But there would be interesting the performance side of the problem. Based on cron rule it should check the rule every second to verify whether to conditions are met. Or do they have this optimized?

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but that is not the way RETE works. Once all the conditions of a rule are met, what you have is an ACTIVATION of the rule. This activation is placed in a place called the AGENDA. If something changes in your session and the conditions of the activated rule are no longer true, the activation is removed from the agenda. When you call fireAllRules() an activation is selected from the agenda and executed. After this, the activation is removed from the agenda. (continue)

Comment: As you can see, there is no reason why drools should periodically check for the conditions of a rule. The conditions are only checked when you insert, modify or retract a fact.

Comment: Yes, I know how RETE works but the catch lies in what the `timer(cron)` extactly does. I understood it as it calls `fireRule()` every time the cron triggers (just as a regular cron) and I am not sure that this is what I want and need. Anyway I will test it and let you know

Comment: This works exactly as I expected. The rule is taken out of the set of regular rules and Drools schedule new `Thread` which fires the rule based on cron definition. And the rule activation is not reported by regular `fireAllRules()`